# Can I know if my page is going to have a scroll bar before it renders. PHP Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a `header.php` which has my `<a name='#top' />`

and I have a `footer.php` which I want to do something like

```
if ($_SERVER[' is scroll bar ']
{
  echo <a href='#top'>Back to Top</a>
}
```

is it possible with PHP or Javascript to do something like this, where I can know if my page is going to be very long ahead of render time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I'm unsure of the practical usefulness of such code. I'm never really certain what a "back to top" or "jump to top" link will do:

- Will it just send me to the top of the page?
- Will it send me to some anchor below the top?
- Will it take me to the top *page*?
- Will it reload (sigh)?

I *do* know what pressing the `Home` key will do, though, and I suspect most people would rather navigate a page using native controls if possible.

Nonetheless, once the page is loaded, you could toggle that kind of link dynamically by setting up event handlers on page resize:

```
var toTopLink = document.getElementById("toTopLink");

function checkLink(e) {
  /*
   * document.height                       = works in most browsers
   * document.body.scrollHeight            = needed in IE
   *
   * window.innerHeight                    = works in most browsers
   * document.documentElement.offsetHeight = IE in compatibility mode
   * document.body.offsetHeight            = IE backwards compatibility
   *
   * In most browsers, document.height equals window.innerHeight if there is no
   * scrollbar. For IE, we test whether the scrollable height is greater than the
   * visible document height.
   */
  if ((document.height || document.body.scrollHeight) >
        (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
         document.body.offsetHeight)) {
    toTopLink.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    toTopLink.style.display = "none";
  }
}

window.onresize = checkLink;
window.onload = checkLink;
```

Different browsers -- by which I mean IE versus everyone else -- have their own ways of finding height, and so the above accounts for that, maybe somewhat redundantly.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible with PHP, don't even try.  Use JavaScript for this, something like:

```
if(document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight){
    // show scroll-to-top link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Without the browser rendering it first, there is no way to know in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I would suggest using JavaScript, instead of PHP. Also, to get the actual size of the page, the content has to be rendered first in the browser.

```
<a href='#top' id="back" style="display:none;">Back to Top</a>
```

Put this JavaScript snippet at the bottom of the page, or in the DOMready callback function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var backAnchor = document.getElementById('back');

    if (document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight) {
        backAnchor.styles.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
```